# MySQL row locking and updating

Tags: mysql

I am running some update queries in the database which update records in bulk and some update each row. At certain times I see MySQL connection queue becomes full and no more connections to MySQL are allowed. This means that some client connection(s) has locked the rows while the other connection is trying to update the same record and waiting for the lock to be removed and thus the connections piles up.

I am unable to figure out which queries are doing that since this happens at split second and I want to see either by `show full processlist` or some other method what's happening in the database.

Really out of ideas here except to update some logic in the application which is time consuming. Really need some pointers here :(

Answer (score 0):

Start with MySQL [slow log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html). Set the threshold to 1-2 seconds and later examine the file. To log all the queries set it to 0. It looks like this, so you will be able to find queries with big lock time:

```
# Time: ...
# User@Host: ...
# Query_time: 160.552078  Lock_time: 0.038823 Rows_sent: 2318  Rows_examined: 2421376
SELECT ...
```